# How do I get only one element from an array php

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON array data

```
{"accessToken":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiJ9.e","refreshToken":"QErx0bUxyx6wxFj5AXcAh21UuyO8ad/ULIaGlP3LU2lmXGnx0twbYdM+nJyfwAcK9Av50uZ3fSZ/2nhJwIi+bA==","expiresIn":"2021-11-11T10:20:33Z","issuedAt":"2021-11-11T10:05:33Z","tokenType":"Bearer"}
```

How do I get only `accessToken` object from the array. i.e `yJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiJ9.e`

This is how I have tried

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
$token = $response['accessToken'];
echo $token;
```

But I get this error

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'accessToken'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
$data = json_decode($response, true);
echo $data['accessToken'];
```

Comment: it is working, I appreciate

Answer (score -1):

try this before trying to access the array

```
json_decode($response, true);
```